Correctness of Solution for Forming a Committee with More Democrats than Republicans
I recently encountered a problem and derived a solution, but I am uncertain about its correctness. Here's the problem:
At a congressional hearing, there are 2n members present. Exactly
n of them are Democrats and n of them are Republicans. The members want to select a
smaller subcommittee of size n from within those present at the hearing. However, since the
Democrats currently hold majority, they want there to be more Democrats then Republicans
in the committee. In how many ways can you select such a committee?
I reasoned that to have more Democrats than Republicans in the committee, there needs to be at least $(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} + 1 \right\rfloor)$ from n Democrats. The number of ways to have these many democrats is: $(\binom{n}{{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} + 1 \right\rfloor}}$
Then select remaining from 2n like so: $\binom{2n - \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} + 1 \right\rfloor}{{\left\lceil \frac{n}{2} - 1 \right\rceil}}$.
Thus, the total number of ways to form the committee is:  $(\binom{n}{{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} + 1 \right\rfloor}} \times \binom{2n - \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} + 1 \right\rfloor}{{\left\lceil \frac{n}{2} - 1 \right\rceil}})$

This is hard to read.  here is a tutorial on formatting for this site.

as to the problem, it's easy to count the unrestricted number of committees of size $n$ and it is easy to count those made from exactly $\frac n2$ of each (assuming $n$ to be even).  Of the rest, exactly half favor the Democrats.

@lulu  Thanks for your response. I edited it. Please check it again

This method overcounts, try some small $n$. The method I described avoids this problem

Note: if $n$ is odd then exactly half of the committees favor Democrats, so that's a very simple formula in that case.

@AzharKhan:  Can all $n$ Democrats form the commitee ?

yeah for n being odd the formula is simple (half of 2n chose n). But what I'm asking is why does my formula above overcounts? what's wrong with the reasoning?

@trueblueanil it wasn't mentioned in question that it cannot be. So by default yes, I guess.

It overcounts because there's no way to keep track of the Democrats that were put in at first as opposed to those that were added later.  As I say,  work small examples.  Always a good idea.

@lulu but I subtracted $\binom{n}{{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} + 1 \right\rfloor}}$ from 2n so that should take care of the fact that the same democrats do not appear in the second

Have you checked your formula against the correct result for small $n$?  Once again, examples are absolutely essential in this sort of thing.  Try $n=3$...that's the first non-trivial case.

@lulu yes I know the correct formula. I just don't know exactly what's wrong with my reasoning. Why does it over count? But I'll try for n = 3 and see if that gives me some clarity as to why my reasoning is wrong

For $n=3$, (and all greater $n$), you are multiply counting the case(s) in which more than the minimal number of democrats appear.  For $n=3$, you count the committee $d_1,d_2,d_3$ three times (according to which of them are picked in the first group).  As you only meant to count it once, your answer should be off by $2$, and indeed you get $12$ while the correct answer is $10$.  After that, the errors become very bad very fast.

To elaborate on the discussion in the comments:
The given method is flawed as it multiply counts any committee that has more than the minimal number of Democrats.
To avoid that, we split into even and odd cases.
If $n$ is odd then exactly half the committees of size $n$ favor the Democrats,  by symmetry.  Thus the answer in that case is $$\frac 12 \times \binom {2n}n$$
If $n=2k$ is even then there are some committees of size $n$ with the same number from both parties. If we exclude those,  then symmetry applies again.  It follows that the answer in this case is $$\frac 12\times \left( \binom {2n}n-\binom nk^2 \right)$$.

Are you allowing zero representation from D,R ?

@trueblueanil  Sure.  The $\binom {2n}n$ term counts all subsets of size $n$, even the two single party subsets.  Of course, the all $D$ subsets is Good for current purposes, and the all $R$ one is Bad, but the $\frac 12$ covers that.

The second multiplier forms a committee from both Democrats and Republicans, so  some Democrat(s) may figure in both parts. Overlapping selections in this manner is a recipe for disaster.
Instead the formula could be
$$\sum_{j = \lfloor \frac{n}{2} + 1 \rfloor}^n \binom{n}{j}\binom{n}{n-j}$$

I Know the correct formula. My only problem is that I can't pinpoint exactly what's wrong with my reasoning. You said in the second multiplier I'm including some democrats as well, but they have to be included because in the first one we make sure that democrats are always at least one more than half of the n i.e 1/2 +1.   In the second we subtract these democrats, so in the rest, there could either be  say 2 democrats not selected in the first and some republicans etc.

@AzharKhan: If you want a message to reach a person, you need to tag that person, I am seeing this just by chance. Re your doubt, suppose a committee of $3$ is to be made from $3D,3R$ with more D than R, (and at least one of each) My solution is  $3c2*3c1 = 9$ But yours would be $3c2 *4c1 =12$ because you have mixed over the excess D in the R group.
